# ttk Button: relief of the button is not taking effect

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have button defined as below:

```
button_style = ttk.Style() 
button_style.configure("button_style.TButton", relief=tk.RAISED, 
                       width = 20, padding=6, font=('Helvetica', 12) ) 
self.button = ttk.Button (self.myContainer1, text="Browse", style='button_style.TButton', 
                          command = self.browse_file) 
self.button.grid(row = 0,column = 3,padx=5, pady=10, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
```

For some reason the relief effect of the button is not applied. Could somebody help me please?
[image]

Comment: The relief of buttons is 'raised' by default, so it is normal that you see no difference with usual relief.

Comment: @j_4321 The Button is not raised. It is sunken .

Comment: @Amit you have clearly stated its `RAISED` in your code. `relief=tk.RAISED`

Comment: I want it to be RAISED but It is SUNKEN when creates the window.

Comment: What OS are you using? have you changed the ttk theme?

Comment: I am working on Win10. I haven't changed the theme. 
Available themes are
 ('winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative')
theme in use vista

Comment: I think that the button is not sunken, it is just how the default ttk theme looks like in Win10. If you don't like it, try changing theme: `button_style.theme_use('clam')`.

Comment: I can see that button relief is raised after changing the theme of the button from 'vista' to 'clam 'using  button_style.theme_use('clam').